# Changed SSH port without allowing it through firewall, locked out now - what to do?

Tags: ssh, firewall

I have a VPS where I changed the SSH port from the default 22. Unfortunately I forgot to allow the new port through the firewall. I don't have physical access to the server, and my host does not seem to offer any shell access to the VPS through their website. Result: I'm locked out of the server. Is there any way I can rectify this short of resetting the server?

Comment: If your provider allows booting to a recovery disk image you could use that to edit the file again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you made the changes by hand and reinvoked `sshd` resetting might help, but if you changed `sshd_config` then resetting the server will not help you, the server will come back up and listen on the new, firewalled, port.

You will have to access the VPS through a console or any other means your provider provides to rectify this kind of problem.

BTW, you can, and should, specify multiple ports in your `sshd_config`:

```
Port 22
Port 2222
```

that way you can test things on the new port before removing the old one, assuming you have to remove the old port in the first place. The only reason I ever had to setup `sshd` to listen to a different port is because a friend's internet provider blocks access to ports below 1025, and his router is not able to map ports, only to allow specific port traffic through, to an internal address.

Comment: Well in this case the "hidden trapdoor" would be in the firewall, so the security of ssh is irrelevant.

Comment: Entering `Joshua` in the prompt should do it..

Comment: @AndréDaniel Right you are.

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask support. The reason I changed the port in the first place was that it was recommendations in several security/hardening tips I came across.

Comment: @cmeeren, that gives you no extra protection if the alternative port is tried and found, but it would thwart simple scanners that only try port 22.

Comment: @cmeeren If this answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will signify to everyone that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site.

Comment: @Anthon thanks, unfortunately it does not really solve my issue since there is still nothing I can do to rectify it myself. I'll simply have to count on technical support having access to the server and reverting back to the default SSH port. They do not provide any means for me to access the server in its current state.

Comment: @cmeeren that is kind of restrictive because they do have that kind of access via the host for the VPS. If this was a root-server there might be physical problems in allowing you access, and that I would understand. If they don't want to give you access to/via the host, they should just mount your current VPS' disc(s) on an a different minimal VPS installation, so you can change the configuration files.

Comment: @Anthon What I meant was that the only option I am left with is contacting tech support (which means _they_ will solve my problem, and which of course was my plan B all along). I have done so now and asked them to change the SSH port back to 22. They do not provide any access to the server other than SSH, though of course they might cook up something only for me now that I have contacted them. I doubt that though, since the easiest solution is for them probably is to change the port themselves.

Comment: @cmeeren Anthon's answer is still correct.  You asked *"Is there any way I can rectify this short of resetting the server?"* and the answer is **No**.