# Connection lost to VPS While using iptables by default policy as DROP for INPUT, OUTPUT, FORWARD

Tags: ssh, iptables, iptables-persistent

I'am using iptables in many server's but now stuck with this issue while using default Policy as DROP.

Here is my rules which i have used in VPS, Tried many time's everything seems fine but VPS getting disconnected when i use this rules.

Only i want ssh port 2222, and ntp for updating my time.

```
iptables -F
iptables -X LOGGING
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 123 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 10/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
```

till logout from VPS i can access VPS it's still established, If once i used to logout and trying to login again i can't login. Will any one review the rules for me ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your rules with regard to incoming traffic on port 2222:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 2222 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 2222 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You aren't allowing NEW connections, so you won't be able to connect from outside.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177223/changed-ssh-port-without-allowing-it-through-firewall-locked-out-now-what-to) might now be of interest.

Comment: i have updated the above rules and tried after adding NEW, but still i can't login into the server.

Comment: fixed it but replacing INPUT chain to dport and OUTPUT to sport..